# http Headers influencing Caching - Tutorial / Documentation

Tags: html, http, caching, browser, proxy

Can somebody point me to decent tutorial explaining the various http-header settings influencing caching (for proxies, the browser, their play-together and possible quirks in browsers and caching engines)

I think it is a somewhat neglected feature --- at least I do not make use of it. Caching CSS, JS and pictures (pretty much everything coming from the cookieless domain) should speed up things a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Caching tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) -- This is pretty good article describing HTTP caching process and related headers.

There is good article about [Optimizing cache](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html) at [Let's make the web faster](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/) website. All articles there are worth checking out.

To speed up a things, you can also:

- reduce number of requests needed to load your page
- compress for your HTTP responses
- combine your CSS/JS files together, and minimize them, for example by using [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) or [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/)
- put small images into one big bundle so that they are loaded using single request ([online tool](http://csssprites.com/) for putting images together)
- Implement [SPDY support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) on your server -- that's probably not something you'll do, but it's interesting idea worth mentioning

Comment: That answer is AWESOME! Many thanks, all appreciated and more than I expected for now, but will look into at a later point.

Comment: @JohnDoe: well, originally I wanted to answer with http://bit.ly/GH7Kff link because that Caching tutorial is #2 result on Google for "http caching". Only after finding that lmgtfy links are not allowed here have I expanded my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) you can find spec, you can refer it.